# OCMock: how to stub -[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, ocmock

I've tried many things. This still does not work:

```
 id stringMock = OCMClassMock([NSString class]);

 [[[[stringMock stub] ignoringNonObjectArgs] stringWithContentsOfURL:[OCMArg anyPointer] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)[OCMArg anyPointer]] andReturn:stringFromFile];
```

How can I make -[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:] return `stringFromFile` anywhere in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible.

From OCMock [documentation](http://ocmock.org/reference/) about the limitations (section 10):

> 10.5 Class methods on NSString cannot be stubbed or verified
>
> id stringMock
> = OCMClassMock([NSString class]); // the following will not work OCMStub([stringMock stringWithContentsOfFile:[OCMArg any]
> encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:[OCMArg setTo:nil]]);
>
> It is not
> possible to stub or verify class methods on NSString. Trying to do so
> has no effect.

You can, however, wrap `NSString` and mock the wrapper. It means that you'll need to replace all the calls in your code with this wrapper, but the tests would work..

**Here's an example:**

The wrapper:

```
@interface NSStringWrapper : NSObject
+ (nullable id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url;
@end

@implementation NSStringWrapper
+ (nullable id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    return [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];
}
@end
```

The test:

```
static NSString *stringFromFile = @"myStringFromFile";

-(void)testStringWrapper
{
    id nsstringWrapperMock = OCMClassMock([NSStringWrapper class]);
    OCMStub(ClassMethod([nsstringWrapperMock stringWithContentsOfURL:OCMOCK_ANY])).andDo(^(NSInvocation *invocation)
    {
      [invocation setReturnValue:&stringFromFile];
    });
    
    NSURL *fakeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"htttp://google.com"];
    NSString *test = [NSStringWrapper stringWithContentsOfURL:fakeURL];
    XCTAssertEqual(test, stringFromFile, @"Should always return stringFromFile");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unit testing is a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to try [OCMockito](https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito), which mocks class methods differently than OCMock.

```
__strong Class mockStringClass = mockClass([NSString class]);
[[given([mockStringClass stringWithContentsOfFile:anything() 
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                            error:NULL])
        withMatcher:anything() forArgument:2]
        willReturn:stringFromFile];
```

Unlike OCMock which swizzles class methods, this requires you to inject the class. That is, instead of production code making a direct call like

```
str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

you need to do something like

```
str = [self.stringClass stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

You should be able to add OCMockito without disrupting your existing use of OCMock.